# Launcher activity not starting first

Tags: java, android

The title explains it pretty much, here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="eu.craym.vulcrum.firstgametnb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="eu.craym.vulcrum.STARTINGPOINT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Yet whenever I run this application, the StartingPoint classed is called first:

```
[2013-03-09 18:36:40 - FirstGameTNB] Starting activity eu.craym.vulcrum.firstgametnb.StartingPoint on device emulator-5554
```

Why is this happening? I thought the MAIN and LAUNCHER were supposed to make it so the Splash class gets called first, but this never happens. Note that when I delete the StartingPoint activity, it goes to Splash.

Comment: No need to define `Intent-Filter` to `activity` StartingPoint. I think you must have used Intent in Splash-Activity to navigate to StartingPoint-Activity.

Comment: How do you "run" your application? Eclipse Run button? Icon on your device?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You may try a clean on your project.

> android.intent.action.MAIN:  Start as a main entry point, does not
>   expect to receive data.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN)